# Including conferences in the CV of an undergraduate student

Tags: conference, cv, research-undergraduate

Do you think it is important to include a list of attended conferences in your CV when you are an **undergraduate student**?

And what about the seminars you have attended which did not provide you with a certificate confirming you took them? Should they be mentioned too?

Comment: I include a list of undergrad attended conferences only if I presented at them. You can bring up other attended conferences in interviews or admission letters if you feel that it contributed to your knowledge/research.

Comment: Okay, but when an undergraduate, you really don't have so many chances to present some work at a conference. That's why I think including such a list, would show you true interest.

Comment: If you're in the US, consider looking into NCUR. Here's another list: http://www.cur.org/resources/students/presentation_opportunities/ I agree that there aren't as many chances to present, but it is important to try if you can. Including a list will show your interest but not your capabilities. If you attend conferences, the networks/contacts you make there are more important than a list on your CV.

Comment: There's also an international conference ( http://www.icurportal.com/ ) I think you can present via video conferencing if you can't travel.

Comment: I just looked into it! Really interesting. Still, not helping when not in U.S.. I didn't find something like that in Europe. Do you have any information about Europe? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> Do you think it is important to include a list of attended conferences in your CV when you are an undergraduate student?

Sure, why not?  It's not likely to make a big difference in graduate school applications, but it can't hurt and might help.  This is not a particularly valuable form of information, but it's worth including when you don't have lots more to say (and undergraduates are generally in that position).

> And what about the seminars you have attended which did not provide you with a certificate confirming you took them? Should they be mentioned too?

In the U.S., certificates confirming attendance are irrelevant. I couldn't recognize an official certificate if I saw one (there's no standard format or protection against forgery), so I consider them meaningless, and this is a common opinion here.  If you are sending your CV to a U.S. institution, then you don't need to worry about this at all.  In other countries the customs may differ, however.

Comment: In my country, there are different opinions about the certificate. Some say it is **not allowed** to include such conferences or seminars and other say: " Why not? Nobody's gonna tell you show me the certificate" . That's why I decided to ask the question over here. However, thanks!